# Wrong redirect after success login

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-client

I have an application that has been working for several years. Login worked as it should, i.e. after redirection to Google login, access granted. The user was redirected to the address provided via `setRedirectUri`. I have been having a problem for a few weeks because suddenly, after successful login, the user is redirected to myaccount.google.com despite no modifications to the code.

I am attaching a code snippet

```php
$credentials_file = $parameterBag->get('google_credentials');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($credentials_file);

$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);

$client->setRedirectUri( $this->router->generate('oauth2callback', [], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL) );
$client->setScopes(self::SCOPES);
$client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');

$code = $request->get('code', null);

if ( !$code ) {

    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    return $this->redirect($auth_url);

} else {
    //magic with logged user
}
```

Comment: What echoes out for `$auth_url`? Also does your Google console have redirect on it? And lastly `oauth2callback`  what's the response from google in this callback?

Comment: @Adi, auth_url looks OK: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Foauth2callback&state&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.business.manage%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&include_granted_scopes=true&prompt=select_account%20consent`

Comment: Did you check the request stack in your devtools, to make sure that it's not redirecting you to `oauth2callback` and this route is itself redirecting you there? If so can you provide the code of the `oauth2callback` controller?

Comment: @unbreak I noticed that your redirect uri includes `https` on a localhost domain, that's a bit unorthodox, are you sure that's correct? And if so make sure the authorized url in the google dashboard also includes this https

Answer (score 1):

Pay very close attention to the Authorized redirect URI in your client ID settings (because this is a web server request you don't need to bother with the javascript origin)

[image]

The **protocol**, the **host**, the **port** and the **path** all need to match exactly what you are sending, any difference would result in google dropping the redirect

I see from your comment the redirect uri you are sending is `https://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth2callback`

Make sure it is exactly what you have in this setting

If it's not that would explain the problem, if you don't have `https` configured locally then pay attention to the config of your app because it seems to generate a `https` url

Comment: Yes, setup is correct. i have https on localhost thanks to symfony server, and that redirect always worked. It start wrong redirecting without any changes...

Comment: thanks for you comment "Did you check the request stack in your devtools,..." this led me in the right direction and I found an error in the code (it's strange that it was OK before), where I redirect the user when the referrer is set, which is the domain in Google...

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you setup your redirect url in the google admin panel.
2. If you are using a local website try using http://localhost as your redirect domain and something like http://localhost/authorize for the redirect url and see if this works first, then change it afterwards if you need to.

[image: google redirect url]

Comment: Of course, it is set, I will point out that everything worked and suddenly this additional redirection appeared.

Comment: I will point out the obvious but `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are considered different domains, and the less obvious but the port and schemes are also matched, make sure the url you send matches perfectly, a change in your config to https might be the culprit